# c++11: dispatch arguments between base classes upon construction

Tags: c++11, inheritance, initializer-list

Assume one has a class derived from two base classes.

```C++
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
};
```

In order to instantiate/construct an object of type `Derived` my initial idea was to use parameter pack. The problem is that I do not know how to dispatch arguments between `Base1` and `Base2` respectively.

```c++
template <typename... TArgs>
Derived(TArgs&&... args)
  : Base1(/* what goes here? */)
  , Base2(/* what goes here? */) {
}
```

I know in advance that `Derived` inherits from only **two** base classes.
My question is whether one has a way construct derived with a syntax similar to the below?

```c++
Derived d({arguments for Base1}, {arguments for Base2});

template <typename T1, typename T2>
Derived : Base1(T1), Base2(T2) {}
```

And if possible then what would be the requirements for the `Base` classes?

How should they accept they construction arguments?

Comment: How about receiving two tuples?

Comment: Indeed, this is an option. Requires a bit of typing for users of such an interface although.

Comment: For what it's worth, the tuple approach is used by `std::pair`, the constructor overload that takes `piecewise_construct`